# Android HERE api drawing many MapMarkers is slow

Tags: android, here-api

I have an application where we need to plot the course of various different vehicles. We need to mark the trail with markers showing which direction they are facing about once every minute. What we end up with is up to 100,000 markers needing to be plotted.

As far as I can tell the only way we can actually plot said marker is by generating a bitmap and passing it to the API, but this ends up using a lot of memory and is unusably slow. I've added caching to the code so that bitmaps aren't generated unless absolutely needed, but it's still too slow. As an example, it takes about **30 seconds** to plot ~10,000 markers on a Nexus 5. Drawing the actual polylines, however, is quite fast (but I need markers along the polyline). MapKit (from Apple) plots an equivalent number of markers in under half a second on an iPhone 5, presumably because we don't have to generate bitmaps. So..

1. What is the recommended way to plot a large number of `MapMarkers`?
2. Is it possible to plot a `Drawable` instead of an `Image`?
3. Also, is there an efficient way to remove all markers from a `Map`? At the moment I have to do it one by one which is, again, unusably slow (`removeMapObjects` simply calls `removeMapObject` in a loop).
4. Should I be going about this in a different way?

It's probably worth mentioning that the slow code is definitely the HERE SDK, and specifically `Map.addMapObjects` and `Map.removeMapObjects`, and I obviously pass in `MapMarker` instances.

Comment: 3. you can use a map overlay. add all markers to the overlay instead of the map and call add/removeMapObject on the overlay to show/hide all markers at once. I didn't tested it but I suppose it must be faster than calling remove on each marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing the following:

```
foreach(MapObject m: myObjects)
    map.addMapObject(m);
```

Then this should help significantly:

```
map.executeSynchronized(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        foreach(MapObject m: myObjects)
            map.addMapObject(m);
    }
});
```

Every time you add a map object it is redrawing the map. Using execute synchronized should batch the update operation to be significantly faster. Also, it is highly recommended you cache any Image objects and re-use the same image if they are identical. Internally the renderer will share the same texture handle.

Comment: That looks like what I'm after! I'll give that a try and then probably mark this as the answer, thanks.

Comment: So that helped a lot, but so did switching to the premium SDK.. Seems to work well now.

Comment: Great! Yes, the premium SDK is much more powerful. Good luck!